Apache Superset Build Error in dev mode when DEV_MODE="false"
When I try to get build with below command I got error.
docker build -t superset-dev --target dev --build-arg DEV_MODE="false" .
I am running in ubuntu, ysing hyper-v,
If I run it DEV_MODE = "true", UI is not building. I am new user of superset try to explore and customize it.
Below is my dockerfile
ARG PY_VER=3.11-slim

# If BUILDPLATFORM is null, set it to 'amd64' (or leave as is otherwise).
ARG BUILDPLATFORM=${BUILDPLATFORM:-amd64}
FROM --platform=${BUILDPLATFORM} node:20-bullseye-slim AS superset-node

ARG NPM_BUILD_CMD="build"
ARG DEV_MODE="false"
ARG INCLUDE_CHROMIUM="true"
ARG INCLUDE_FIREFOX="false"

# Install system dependencies for Node.js
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        python3 \
        zstd \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV BUILD_CMD=${NPM_BUILD_CMD} \
    PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true

WORKDIR /app/superset-frontend

# Creating empty folders to avoid errors when running COPY later on
RUN mkdir -p /app/superset/static/assets /app/superset/translations

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json before running npm ci
COPY superset-frontend/package.json superset-frontend/package-lock.json ./


# Install Node.js dependencies
RUN if [ "$DEV_MODE" = "false" ]; then \
        npm install --legacy-peer-deps; \
    else \
        echo "Skipping 'npm install' in dev mode"; \
    fi


# Build frontend assets using npm
COPY superset-frontend /app/superset-frontend
RUN if [ "$DEV_MODE" = "false" ]; then \
        npm run ${BUILD_CMD}; \
    else \
        echo "Skipping 'npm run ${BUILD_CMD}' in dev mode"; \
    fi

# Copy and compile translations
RUN mkdir -p /app/superset/translations
COPY superset/translations /app/superset/translations
RUN if [ "$DEV_MODE" = "false" ]; then \
        npm run build-translation; \
    else \
        echo "Skipping translations in dev mode"; \
    fi
RUN rm /app/superset/translations/*/LC_MESSAGES/*.po
RUN rm /app/superset/translations/messages.pot

######################################################################
# Base Python image with Oracle Instant Client
######################################################################
FROM python:${PY_VER} AS base

WORKDIR /app

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    SUPERSET_ENV=production \
    FLASK_APP="superset.app:create_app()" \
    PYTHONPATH="/app/pythonpath" \
    SUPERSET_HOME="/app/superset_home" \
    SUPERSET_PORT=8088 \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_19 \
    TNS_ADMIN=/app/superset

# Install system dependencies (including Oracle Instant Client dependencies)
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        libaio1 \
        unzip \
        curl \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit \
        libpq-dev \
        libecpg-dev \
        libldap2-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Oracle Instant Client setup
COPY instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.19.0.0.0dbru.el9.zip /opt/oracle/
COPY instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.19.0.0.0dbru.el9.zip /opt/oracle/
RUN unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.19.0.0.0dbru.el9.zip -d /opt/oracle/ \
    && unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.19.0.0.0dbru.el9.zip -d /opt/oracle/ \
    && rm /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.19.0.0.0dbru.el9.zip \
    && rm /opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.19.0.0.0dbru.el9.zip

# Install OracleDB Python package before running Superset commands
RUN pip install oracledb

# Create necessary directories and user
RUN mkdir -p ${PYTHONPATH} superset/static requirements superset-frontend apache_superset.egg-info \
    && useradd --user-group -d ${SUPERSET_HOME} -m --no-log-init --shell /bin/bash superset \
    && touch superset/static/version_info.json

# Install build-essential temporarily for pip installations that require compilation
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
      build-essential \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy and install Python dependencies
COPY pyproject.toml setup.py MANIFEST.in README.md ./
COPY superset-frontend/package.json superset-frontend/
COPY requirements/base.txt requirements/
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools pip \
    && pip install -r requirements/base.txt

# Copy Superset source code
COPY superset superset

# Copy superset_config.py for Oracle DB configuration
COPY docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py /app/superset/superset_config.py

# Set environment variables for Superset to point to the config file
ENV SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/app/superset/superset_config.py

# Install Superset
RUN pip install -e .

# Create an admin user for Superset during build
RUN superset fab create-admin --username admin --firstname Admin --lastname User \
    --email admin@example.com --password admin

# Initialize the Superset database
RUN superset db upgrade

# Remove build-essential to keep the image lean
RUN apt-get purge -yqq build-essential \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Change ownership of /app directory to superset user
RUN chown -R superset:superset /app

# Switch to superset user
USER superset

# Copy the compiled frontend assets from the superset-node stage
COPY --chown=superset:superset --from=superset-node /app/superset/static/assets superset/static/assets
COPY --chown=superset:superset --from=superset-node /app/superset/translations superset/translations

# Copy and set permissions for the entrypoint script
COPY --chmod=755 docker/run-server.sh /usr/bin/

# Copy translation script
COPY --chown=superset:superset scripts/translations/generate_mo_files.sh scripts/translations/

# Run the translation script
RUN scripts/translations/generate_mo_files.sh \
    && rm superset/translations/messages.pot \
    && rm superset/translations/*/LC_MESSAGES/*.po

# Healthcheck to check if the app is running
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -f "http://localhost:${SUPERSET_PORT}/health" || exit 1

EXPOSE ${SUPERSET_PORT}

######################################################################
# Development Image
######################################################################
FROM base AS dev

# Switch to root to install development dependencies
USER root

# Install development dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        git \
        pkg-config \
        libnss3 \
        libdbus-glib-1-2 \
        libgtk-3-0 \
        libx11-xcb1 \
        libasound2 \
        libxtst6 \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        libldap2-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Playwright and its dependencies
RUN pip install playwright \
    && playwright install-deps

RUN if [ "$INCLUDE_CHROMIUM" = "true" ]; then \
        playwright install chromium; \
    else \
        echo "Skipping Chromium installation"; \
    fi

# Install Firefox and GeckoDriver if needed
ARG GECKODRIVER_VERSION=v0.34.0 \
    FIREFOX_VERSION=125.0.3

RUN if [ "$INCLUDE_FIREFOX" = "true" ]; then \
        apt-get update -qq \
        && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends wget bzip2 \
        && wget -q https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/${GECKODRIVER_VERSION}/geckodriver-${GECKODRIVER_VERSION}-linux64.tar.gz -O - | tar xfz - -C /usr/local/bin \
        && wget -q https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/${FIREFOX_VERSION}/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-${FIREFOX_VERSION}.tar.bz2 -O - | tar xfj - -C /opt \
        && ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox \
        && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge wget bzip2 \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    fi

# Install development Python dependencies
COPY requirements/development.txt requirements/
RUN pip install -r requirements/development.txt

# Change ownership of /app directory to superset user
RUN chown -R superset:superset /app

# Switch back to superset user
USER superset

CMD ["/usr/bin/run-server.sh"]


Below is what I got when I try to get build.
183.1 WARNING in ./src/utils/textUtils.ts 21:11-44
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../superset_text' in '/app/superset-frontend/src/utils'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./node_modules/@visx/react-spring/lib/axis/AnimatedTicks.js 6:11-39
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/web' in '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/@visx/react-spring/lib/axis'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./node_modules/@visx/react-spring/lib/grid/AnimatedGridLines.js 7:11-39
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/web' in '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/@visx/react-spring/lib/grid'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./node_modules/@visx/xychart/esm/components/annotation/AnimatedAnnotation.js 7:0-60
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/web' in '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/@visx/xychart/esm/components/annotation'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./node_modules/@visx/xychart/esm/components/series/private/AnimatedBars.js 7:0-60
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/web' in '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/@visx/xychart/esm/components/series/private'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./node_modules/@visx/xychart/esm/components/series/private/AnimatedGlyphs.js 3:0-64
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/web' in '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/@visx/xychart/esm/components/series/private'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./node_modules/@visx/xychart/esm/components/series/private/AnimatedPath.js 5:0-56
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@react-spring/web' in '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/@visx/xychart/esm/components/series/private'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./node_modules/@encodable/registry/esm/models/Registry.js 4:0-39
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'global-box' in '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/@encodable/registry/esm/models'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./plugins/plugin-chart-handlebars/node_modules/just-handlebars-helpers/lib/helpers/formatters.js 27:24-55
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'currencyformatter.js' in '/app/superset-frontend/plugins/plugin-chart-handlebars/node_modules/just-handlebars-helpers/lib/helpers'
183.1 
183.1 ERROR in ./node_modules/encodable/esm/options/Encodable.js 3:0-38
183.1 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'global-box' in '/app/superset-frontend/node_modules/encodable/esm/options'
183.1 
183.1 webpack 5.94.0 compiled with 9 errors and 1 warning in 169936 ms
------
Dockerfile:40
--------------------
  39 |     COPY superset-frontend /app/superset-frontend
  40 | >>> RUN if [ "$DEV_MODE" = "false" ]; then \
  41 | >>>         npm run ${BUILD_CMD}; \
  42 | >>>     else \
  43 | >>>         echo "Skipping 'npm run ${BUILD_CMD}' in dev mode"; \
  44 | >>>     fi
  45 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ \"$DEV_MODE\" = \"false\" ]; then         npm run ${BUILD_CMD};     else         echo \"Skipping 'npm run ${BUILD_CMD}' in dev mode\";     fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


I have prepared my dockerfile and try to get build getting error.
I can get build with DEV_MODE = true

A couple of general tips: you don't need the Instant Client SDK for python-oracledb. And unless you want to use the python-oracledb 'Thick' mode, you don't need any Instant Client package at all.  However if you do want it, then I recommend running ldconfig instead of setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, since the latter can get ignored.  Read the python-oracledb installation doc.  You may also be interested in Steps to use Apache Superset and Oracle Database.

Thanks! actually I have followed that article, since I need to connect it to oracle 11gR2, I can handle it like that. But, I am new and trying to learn, there might be missing points. trying to learn that.
